# Does the AWS CLI mv command also do a copy-and-delete?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am investigating renaming bundles in AWS S3. I would prefer to use the SDK, but it appears that the SDK only supports Copy and Delete. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184720/how-to-rename-files-and-folder-in-amazon-s3)  because the object keys are used for partitoning the drive.

However, the AWS CLI does provide a mv functionality, according to its [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html).

Is this just a wrapper to the copy-and-delete operations (likely), or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It can't be anything else, since S3's REST interface does not support a "move" or "rename" operation, only the "put/copy" operation, which allows objects to be copied inside S3 from one key to another (including across buckets, even when the buckets are in two different regions, as long as a single set of credentials has sufficient privilege) without the need to first download and then upload the object.

Comment: That's how I read it too. Vainly hoping there was maybe a move to more filesystem-like semantics that hadn't made it to the API yet.  Although given that the CLI probably uses the API.... right.